# PL/SQL select from two tables

Tags: sql, oracle

Having these two tables, as an example:

```
CREATE TABLE DEPT(
 deptno number(2) NOT NULL,
 DNAME varchar2(13)
);

CREATE TABLE EMP(
 EMPNO number(4) NOT NULL,
 ENAME varchar2(13),
 DEPTNO NUMBER(2) NOT NULL (this is referencing DEPT (DEPTNO)
);
```

I want to select the names of the employees that are working in the 'Accounting' and 'Sales' departments, so I would do this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW EXAMPLE
AS
SELECT ENAME, DNAME FROM EMP, DEPT
WHERE DNAME IN ('ACCOUNTING','SALES);
```

But I'm not sure at all this is the right way to do this. Should I be joining the ename with the dname

where ename.dname IN ('ACCOUNTING','SALES') maybe?

Thank you in advance

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Thank you! checkin JOIN right now.

Comment: There is no PL/SQL in your question - only plain SQL

Answer (score 0):

You should join EMP table with DEPT table by DEPTNO column.
After that using the condition WHERE DNAME IN ('ACCOUNTING','SALES')
The query is look like below:

```
SELECT e.ENAME, d.DNAME 
FROM EMP e
left join DEPT d on d.DEPTNO = e.DEPTNO
WHERE d.DNAME IN ('ACCOUNTING','SALES');
```

Comment: Thank you, for some reason we haven't seen JOIN in our classes, this looks a lot better and clearer.

Comment: Actually it should be `from DEPT left join EMP on ...` as the foreign key means there can be departments without employees but not vice versa

Comment: @A. Reig: Change the class then if you can. Comma-separated joins were made reduandant by explicit ANSI joins in 1992! (It took Oracle ten years to adopt them, though, but that was still fifteen years ago.) The out-dated syntax should be mentioned, but not taught.

Comment: @ThucVu: That should be an inner join. It's a strange habit to use outer joins everywhere, no matter whether they are actually needed. In a query that shall select the employees of two departments, there is no need for an outer join. (Well, your WHERE clause converts your outer join into an inner join silently, but thus obfuscating matters even more.)